# Jquery UI Dialog Block North, South Resizing handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can anybody please tell me how can i block the Re-sizing position (North, South) side in Jquery Dialog UI.

We have handle property in Jquery UI Re-sizable which do the the same thing but if the same property we set over here it dosen't work. I have created the sample jsfiddle for your reference please check and suggest me something : http://jsbin.com/yeleziyuno/edit?html,output

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( {resizable: true, handles: 'se' });
```

Thanks
Ricky

Comment: While it's OK and even good to include a jsbin link to your question, you should still include the relevant piece of code in your question.

Comment: ok I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone, I am able to solve this thing.

Just added the below code @ the time of opening up of modal dialog. Some-one can please atleast tell me whether my approach was ok or something better option was still available.

```
 $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-n').hide();
                    $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-e').hide();
                    $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-s').hide();
                    $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-w').hide();
                    $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-sw').hide();
                    $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-ne').hide();
                    $('div.ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-nw').hide();
```